# Hard refresh website design

Tags: page-refresh

I am developing a site, but every time I do a small change I have to perform a hard refresh in order to see the change.

The obvious question here is that a **user probably will never do a hard refresh, and so he/she will not see the effects immediately**. Plus, sometimes when I change the stylesheet,
without hard refresh the site looks like a mess.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the page not to cache by adding cache control meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

You can also prevent caching of your stylesheet by adding a version get parameter:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css?v=1" type="text/css" />
```

Increment the version number to force a new version to be loaded.

Comment: Of course this will slow your page down as all the content will be fetched from the server each time, so the meta tags should be removed eventually.

Comment: It depends. If this is a dynamic website which displays user personalized content (logged in name, inbox messages etc) then the cache headers are mandatory.

Comment: +1 for a solution that would work, but... if the OP has control over the actual `HTTP` headers, it would be cleaner to set those rather than rely on the `<meta>` tags. Also, using the "real thing" (the actual headers) would also work for the stylesheet and other non-HTML resources (JS, imgs, etc), without the ugly `v` parameter.

Comment: Thanks man, actually I don't want to prevent caching, but I tried to reload the stylesheet every time the page loads and it works like a charm.

Here is how it looks like:

`code`<link rel="stylesheet" href=<?php echo $cssPath."styles.css?".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') ?> type="text/css" media="screen" />`code`

Comment: If you have enough control of the server, try to ensure that it deals with the `If-Modified-Since` (look it up) header properly, and that your files have a good timestamp. That header exists for the sole purpose of doing what you are asking: enable caching, but make sure the resource is served again if it has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

So, the changes in your design (external stylesheets?) are not immediately showing?

This probably has to do with the browser cache. 
Your files are cached, which is a good thing. If you want to invalidate the cache, you might add a parameter to your external files, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css**?v=f023310c4326**">
```

The developers of this awesome piece of software know all about this.