# Non-HTTP URL (used to call a phone's SMS app) only intermittently successful on the same device, what could be the cause?

Tags: python, html, django, url

I'm calling a non-http url from my Django app. The URL is `sms:14085701890?body:Hello and visit my website at example.com`. This is actually an HTML trick: calling that opens the native SMS app of the mobile device, and prefills **1-408-570-1890** in the `to` field, and **Hello and visit my website at example.com** in the `body` field of the SMS.

I tried sending this response via a view - but all non-http responses are considered unsafe - and over-riding this behavior has cost me a lot of time without a solution.

So instead, currently the view just renders a response to a template that has the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL={{ url }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>Please wait...</b><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using `meta http-equiv="refresh"` in `head` automatically redirects me to the SMS app with `{{ url }}` prefilled (where `url` = `sms:<number>?body:<body>`). This set up gets the job done for me, but there's a problem.

**The problem:** After my SMS app gets pre-filled correctly, I just go back and try the whole thing all over again, and what I notice is that the second time around, **the body text in the SMS turns up completely blank**. If I keep re-trying, I have a ~50% failure rate (`body` pre-fills correctly ~50% of the time, otherwise it's just blank - though the number always correctly pre-fills).

Strange part is, if I print the `{{ url }}` in the template above, the url gets correctly printed **every time**, meaning the `body` text was formed correctly by my code *every time*.

What on earth could be going on? I'm out of leads. Perhaps someone can creatively guesstimate what might be going on, and what can I do to fix this. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: [Caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?, Does adding the top two meta lines from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522718/1324033) help?

Comment: Yea either caching, or some kind of an anti-spam feature? I'm going to start with trying out what you suggested.